# Declaring Variable based on Select inside a function in Postgres 9

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a simple postgres function but something is wrong.

Basically I want to execute one select, using some parameters, store the result, and reuse it for another select.

Here is the Function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateCrossCompanyValues (fromCompany TEXT, toCompany TEXT, timemillis TEXT)
RETURNS decimal AS $finalValue$
DECLARE
    periodStart text;
    fromValue decimal;
    toValue decimal;
    finalValue decimal;
BEGIN
    periodStart := 'select period_start from company_updates where period_start <='|| timemillis || ' and period_end >= ' || timemillis;
    fromValue := 'select cvalue from company_values where id_company = '|| fromCompany ||' and updated_on = ' || periodStart;
    toValue := 'select cvalue from company_values where id_company = '|| toCompany ||' and updated_on = ' || periodStart;
    
    finalValue := round(fromValue::numeric / toValue::numeric, 12);
    
    RETURN finalValue;
END;
$finalValue$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "Postgres 9" covers 7 major version of which 5 are no longer supported. What is the exact version you are using?

Comment: "Something is wrong" is not a clear problem statement. Are you getting an error message? A result that is not what you expected? Please click [edit] and be as specific as you can, ideally including a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you declaring a parameter named `timemillis` as `text` - with that name I would expect a `bigint`. Same for `periodStart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing any query, you are trying to assign a string value to a value.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) you need to use `select .. into variable from ..` in PL/pgSQL to store the result of a query into a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateCrossCompanyValues (fromCompany TEXT, toCompany TEXT, timemillis TEXT)
RETURNS decimal AS $finalValue$
DECLARE
    periodStart text;
    fromValue decimal;
    toValue decimal;
    finalValue decimal;
BEGIN
    select period_start 
      into periodStart 
    from company_updates 
    where period_start <= timemillis 
      and period_end >= timemillis;
      
    select cvalue 
       into fromValue 
    from company_values 
    where id_company = fromCompany 
      and updated_on = periodStart;
      
    select cvalue 
        into toValue 
    from company_values 
    where id_company = toCompany 
      and updated_on = periodStart;
    
    finalValue := round(fromValue::numeric / toValue::numeric, 12);
    
    RETURN finalValue;
END;
$finalValue$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now!